# Assembly Language to C issue with registers

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, att

I am trying to write C code that will have an effect equivalent to the following assembly code:

```
addq %rsi, %rdi
imulq %rdx, %rdi
movq %rdi, %rax
sarq $15, %rax
salq $31, %rax
andq %rdi, %rax
ret
```

With a function prototype

long decode(long x, long y, long z)

Parameters x, y, and z are passed in registers %rdi, %rsi, and %rdx. The code stores the return value in register %rax.

So far I have the following C code:

```
long decode(long x, long y, long z)
{
  long w;

  x = x+y;
  x = x*z;

  w = x;
  w = ((x>>15)<<31);

  return x&w;
}
```

Which, when compiled with the gcc -O2 -S -c filename.c produces the following:

```
addq %rdi, %rsi
imulq %rdx, %rsi
movq %rsi, %rax
sarq $15, %rax
salq $31, %rax
andq %rsi, %rax
ret
```

Apparently, the registers %rdi and %rsi are swapped.

So, if I change the function by swapping x and y, it looks like this:

```
long decode4(long x, long y, long z)
{
  long w;

  y = x + y;
  y = y * z;

  w = y;
  w = ((y>>15)<<31);

  return y&w;
}
```

And, again the assembly looks like this:

```
 addq %rdi, %rsi
 imulq %rdx, %rsi
 movq %rsi, %rax
 sarq $15, %rax
 salq $31, %rax
 andq %rsi, %rax
 ret
```

The swapping of y and x, did not change a thing in the assembly code produced.
Any ideas of how to fix that issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using `x` for result, use `y`.

Comment: Apparently you've swapped `x` and `y`, e.g. `x = x*z` should be `y = y*z`, etc.

Comment: Is that what you mean?
     long decode(long x, long y, long z)
     {
      long w;
      y = x+y;
      y = x*z;
      w = y;
      w = ((y>>15)<<31);
      return y&w;
      }

With this code, the first operation y = x+y; is not converted into assembly (addq %rsi, %rdi)

Comment: What difference does it make which register the compiler decides to use as a scratch register? There's no way to force it to use the register you want. I'm actually surprised you were able to get it as close as it is.

Comment: That produces the original result with the swapped %rdi and rsi% registers.
     addq %rdi, %rsi
     imulq %rdx, %rsi
movq %rsi, %rax
     sarq $15, %rax
     salq $31, %rax
     andq %rsi, %rax
     ret

Comment: I think you need to add your updated code to the question.

Comment: @user3386109, once x+y is computed, those function arguments aren't used again, so the register that the compiler uses to hold the sum of x and y is effectively a scratch register, and the compiler can put the sum in any register it wants.

Comment: Your original question asked for "C code that will have an effect equivalent to the following assembly code". The  C code you have written meets that requirement. There's no way to control the compiler's register selection. Can you explain why you think this is an "issue"?

Comment: By the way, there's an extraneous `w = x;`.

Comment: @pri Yup, you're right.

Comment: I was not sure if it should produce the same assembly code or not. Now I understand that it does not have to be the same. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly.  Leftover temporaries in call-clobbered registers (other than the return-value) are not considered an observable side-effect of a C function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't anything wrong with your interpretation of the code:

```
long decode(long x, long y, long z)
{
  long w;

  x = x+y;
  x = x*z;

  w = x;
  w = ((x>>15)<<31);

  return x&w;
}
```

It could be simplified a bit, but there isn't anything wrong with it given that the output is different only in the reversal of the registers used. The observable result would be the same. You state this requirement:

> I am trying to write C code that will have an effect **equivalent** to the following assembly

The two are **equivalent** so I believe the assignment has been satisfied by your solution.

---

Some times this type of thing can come down to the compiler used. I noticed that I can get the exact output you are looking for with GCC 4.6.4 and `-O2` optimization level. You can play with this code on [godbolt](http://long%20decode(long%20x,%20long%20y,%20long%20z)%20%7B%20%20%20long%20w;%20%20%20%20x%20=%20x+y;%20%20%20x%20=%20x*z;%20%20%20%20w%20=%20x;%20%20%20w%20=%20((x%3E%3E15)%3C%3C31);%20%20%20%20return%20x&w;%20%20%7D%20%20long%20decode2(long%20x,%20long%20y,%20long%20z)%20%7B%20%20%20x%20=%20(x%20+%20y)%20*%20z;%20%20%20return%20x%20&%20((x%20%3E%3E%2015)%20%3C%3C%2031);%20%7D) where the output is:

```
decode:
        addq    %rsi, %rdi
        imulq   %rdx, %rdi
        movq    %rdi, %rax
        sarq    $15, %rax
        salq    $31, %rax
        andq    %rdi, %rax
        ret
```

This seems to be an exact match with your course's output. Using the same version of GCC (4.6.4) you can get the same output with:

```
long decode(long x, long y, long z)
{
  x = (x + y) * z;
  return x & ((x >> 15) << 31);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has optimized your code so you don't see any difference in assembly code after swapping x and y.

Your code is treated as below by the compiler,

```
long decode4(long x, long y, long z)
{
    long w;
    // y = x + y;
    // y = y * z;
    // w = y;

    // The above three lines are combined as
    x = (x + y)*z; // result of addition and multiplication in rsi
    w = x; // move the above result to rax

    //w = ((y>>15)<<31);
    //return y&w;

    //The above two lines are treated as
    w = ((w>>15)<<31); // shift operations on rax
    return x&w; // rax and rsi
}
```

Change in x or y is not going to affect the intended behaviour of this function so the compiler has optimized it.

Hope this helps you.

You can also try compiling your code with optimization O0 (no optimization) then you can see change in assembly code as you expected.